# Plug-in keyboard not working but plug in mouse is on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I upgraded to 22.04 weeks ago and my plug-in keyboard and mouse both worked fine. However, last week I used the laptop elsewhere and used the built-in keyboard and mouse. Since then, I used the laptop with the plug-ins and it was working. Today after booting the mouse works but not the keyboard. They are plugged into a usb port hub as always. I did have my Android phone plugged in for a file transfer. Unplugging that made no difference.
Lenovo Thinkpad E420

The command cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type returns 10.

Others have reported the built-in keyboard not working but mine is. Going to try a reboot and see if that does anything and report back.

Comment: Neither reboot nor power off restores the plug-in keyboard.

Comment: The results of dmidecode -t system: SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
 Manufacturer: LENOVO
 Product Name: 1141BUU
 Version: ThinkPad E420
 Serial Number: R9ML898
 UUID: 1fb3e601-5178-11cb-b32d-f9b041e9045d
 Wake-up Type: Power Switch
 SKU Number: <BAD INDEX>
 Family: <BAD INDEX>  Other than SKU and Family it looks correct.

Answer (score -1):

This turned out to be a hardware problem. The keyboard was in scroll lock but wouldn't toggle off with the scroll lock key. I unplugged the keyboard which turned off scroll lock. Plugged it back in and now it's working.

Don't know how scroll lock was turned on. I don't use the keys in the upper right corner of the board but once in a blue moon and have never used scroll lock.